# How can I use intent to navigate to another screen by clicking recyclerview object in Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Hi I am a beginner at using API's and I want to implement a onClick that will show details of the item that has been clicked, by navigating from Main Activity to Movie Activity

**Activity_movie.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_margin="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTitle"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/big_shoulders_text"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bad_script"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/banner" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My **MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    private val api = retrofit.create(MovieAPI ::class.java)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        api.getMovies().enqueue(object : Callback<Movies>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Movies>, response: Response<Movies>) {
               val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
                recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                val adapter = MovieAdapter(response.body()!!,this@MainActivity)
                recyclerview.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Movies>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("It's not working!",t.message!!)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**MovieActivity.kt**

```
    class MovieActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie)
            val movietitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTitle)
            val movieDesc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textDescription)
            val movieBanner = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.banner)
    
        }
    }
```

And Finally **MovieAdapter.kt**

```
class MovieAdapter(val movies: List<MoviesItem>,val activity: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
     val txtTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTitle)
        val img = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        val txtYear = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtYear)
        val movietitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTitle)
        val movieDesc = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textDescription)
        val banner = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.banner)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie : MoviesItem = movies[position]
        //Main Activity items
        holder.txtTitle.setText(movie.title)
        holder.txtYear.setText(movie.releaseDate)
        Glide.with(activity).load(movie.image).into(holder.img)
        //Movie activity items
        holder.movietitle.setText(movie.title)
        holder.movieDesc.setText(movie.description)
        Glide.with(activity).load(movie.movieBanner).into(holder.banner)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.movie_look,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

}
```

Again I am a beginner at this and couldn't find much information on this specific issue
Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: In movieAdapter.kt ,in onBindViewHolder, add onClick listener to any view. e.g. 
```holder.banner.setOnClickListener { startActivity(...)
        }
```
this is just a hint, I think you can get your answer by this way

Comment: I added `holder.img.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(activity,MovieActivity::class.java)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        }` and it now navigates but there is only problem left now how do I load the clicked item's data to next screen's fields

Comment: You can pass some kind of data using intent like ```intent.putExtra()```. please refer this [link](https://medium.com/android-news/passing-data-between-activities-using-intent-in-android-85cb097f3016)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass it to the adapter and call it in onClick on some item in the viewHolder

```
class MovieAdapter(
    val movies: List<MoviesItem>,
    val activity: Activity,
    val onClickListener: (Int) -> Unit
    //val onClickListener: (MoviesItem) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    ...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie : MoviesItem = movies[position]
        //Main Activity items
        holder.txtTitle.setText(movie.title)
        holder.txtYear.setText(movie.releaseDate)
        Glide.with(activity).load(movie.image).into(holder.img)
        //Movie activity items
        holder.movietitle.setText(movie.title)
        holder.movieDesc.setText(movie.description)
        Glide.with(activity).load(movie.movieBanner).into(holder.banner)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onClickListener(position/movie) }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it with lambda:

```
MovieAdapter(response.body()!!,this@MainActivity) { movie ->
    // Move to the $movie
}
```